# WTSQuerySessionInformation returning empty strings

Tags: c++, terminal-services, wtsapi32

I've written a program which should query the Terminal Services API and print out some state information about the sessions running on a terminal services box.  I'm using the WTSQuerySessionInformation function to do this and it's returning some data but most of the data seems to be missing... Does anyone know why?

Here's my program:

```
void WTSGetString( HANDLE serverHandle, DWORD sessionid, WTS_INFO_CLASS command, wchar_t* commandStr) 
{
    DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
    LPTSTR pData = NULL;
    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, sessionid, command, &pData, &bytesReturned))
    {
        wprintf(L"\tWTSQuerySessionInformationW - session %d - %s returned \"%s\"\n", sessionid, commandStr, pData);    
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"\tWTSQuerySessionInformationW - session %d - %s failed - error=%d - ", sessionid, commandStr, GetLastError());
        printLastError(NULL, GetLastError());
    }
    WTSFreeMemory(pData);
}


void ExtractFromWTS( HANDLE serverHandle, DWORD sessionid ) 
{

    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSInitialProgram, L"WTSInitialProgram");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSApplicationName, L"WTSApplicationName");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSWorkingDirectory, L"WTSWorkingDirectory");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSOEMId, L"WTSOEMId");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSSessionId, L"WTSSessionId");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSUserName, L"WTSUserName");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSWinStationName, L"WTSWinStationName");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSDomainName, L"WTSDomainName");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSConnectState, L"WTSConnectState");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSClientBuildNumber, L"WTSClientBuildNumber");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSClientName, L"WTSClientName");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSClientDirectory, L"WTSClientDirectory");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSClientProductId, L"WTSClientProductId");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSClientHardwareId, L"WTSClientHardwareId");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSClientAddress, L"WTSClientAddress");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSClientDisplay, L"WTSClientDisplay");
    WTSGetString(serverHandle, sessionid, WTSClientProtocolType, L"WTSClientProtocolType");
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PWTS_SESSION_INFOW ppSessionInfo = 0;
    DWORD pCount;
    if(!WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &ppSessionInfo, &pCount))
    {
        printLastError(L"WTSEnumerateSessions", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    wprintf(L"%d WTS sessions found on host\n", pCount);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<pCount; i++)
    {
        wprintf(L"> session=%d, stationName = %s\n", ppSessionInfo[i].SessionId, ppSessionInfo[i].pWinStationName);
        ExtractFromWTS(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, ppSessionInfo[i].SessionId);
        LPWSTR sessionstr = new wchar_t[200];
        wsprintf(sessionstr, L"%d", ppSessionInfo[i].SessionId);    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>ObtainWTSStartShell.exe empserver1
4 WTS sessions found on host
> session=0, stationName = Services
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSInitialProgram failed - error=87 - The paramete
r is incorrect.

        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSApplicationName failed - error=87 - The paramet
er is incorrect.

        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSWorkingDirectory returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSOEMId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSSessionId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSUserName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSWinStationName returned "Services"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSDomainName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSConnectState returned "♦"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSClientBuildNumber returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSClientName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSClientDirectory returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSClientProductId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSClientHardwareId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSClientAddress returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSClientDisplay returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 0 - WTSClientProtocolType returned ""
        GetShellProcessNameFromUserPolicy - Error: Unable to open policy key - returned [2]
        GetShellProcessName succeseded - explorer.exe
> session=1, stationName = Console
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSInitialProgram returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSApplicationName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSWorkingDirectory returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSOEMId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSSessionId returned "☺"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSUserName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSWinStationName returned "Console"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSDomainName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSConnectState returned "☺"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSClientBuildNumber returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSClientName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSClientDirectory returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSClientProductId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSClientHardwareId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSClientAddress returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSClientDisplay returned "?"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 1 - WTSClientProtocolType returned ""
        GetShellProcessNameFromUserPolicy - Error: Unable to open policy key - returned [2]
        GetShellProcessName succeseded - explorer.exe
> session=3, stationName = RDP-Tcp#0
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSInitialProgram returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSApplicationName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSWorkingDirectory returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSOEMId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSSessionId returned "♥"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSUserName returned "Administrator"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSWinStationName returned "RDP-Tcp#0"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSDomainName returned "EMPSERVER1"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSConnectState returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSClientBuildNumber returned "?"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSClientName returned "APWADEV03"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSClientDirectory returned "C:\Windows\System32\m
stscax.dll"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSClientProductId returned "☺"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSClientHardwareId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSClientAddress returned "☻"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSClientDisplay returned "?"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 3 - WTSClientProtocolType returned "☻"
        GetShellProcessNameFromUserPolicy - Error: Unable to open policy key - returned [2]
        GetShellProcessName succeseded - explorer.exe
> session=65536, stationName = RDP-Tcp
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSInitialProgram returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSApplicationName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSWorkingDirectory returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSOEMId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSSessionId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSUserName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSWinStationName returned "RDP-Tcp"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSDomainName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSConnectState returned "♠"
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSClientBuildNumber returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSClientName returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSClientDirectory returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSClientProductId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSClientHardwareId returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSClientAddress returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSClientDisplay returned ""
        WTSQuerySessionInformationW - session 65536 - WTSClientProtocolType returned ""
        GetShellProcessNameFromUserPolicy - Error: Unable to open policy key - returned [2]
        GetShellProcessName succeseded - explorer.exe
```

As you can see, some of the data looks valid, but not all....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, the answer appears to be that it's fairly normal for these fields to be empty on a terminal services/RDP session.  This API was originally a Citrix API and there's a WF equivalent to most of these WTS function.  You seem to get much more data from my program when running on a Citrix/IDA server which appears to implement this session API much more fully.  Having said that, I also saw more of the fields being filled in when using MS Remote App.  However, essentially my program was working...

Answer (score 3):

Even though WTSQuerySessionInformation takes a LPTSTR to hold the data returned, the data isn't always a string. Trying to printf something that isn't a string won't work very well in most cases. The fact that you're seeing empty/garbage strings means that sometimes the buffer pointed to by the LPTSTR starts with a '\0' if read as a string, which printf will print as the empty string.

Instead try printing out each character of the string in HEX representation. Iterate through each character in the string (0 through bytesReturned-1) and print it as hex. That will give you a better idea of what's in the LPTSTR buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to get anything but the current session stuff.

```
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {

        //  if(!WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &ppSessionInfo, &pCount))
        //  {
        ////The stuff coming back from WTSEnumerateSessions in ppSessionInfo doesn't seem to be useful. 

        if (GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION) == 0)
        {
            //it ain't remote.  give up.
            return 1;
        }

        DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
        LPTSTR pData = NULL;
        WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTSSessionId, &pData, &bytesReturned);
        DWORD sessionId = pData[0]; /*for lookin' at in the debugger*/
        wprintf(L"%d WTS session where you will see stuff.  CURRENT_SESSION\n", pData[0]);

        ExtractFromWTS(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, pData[0]); 
        LPWSTR sessionstr = new wchar_t[200];
        wsprintf(sessionstr, L"%d", pData[0]);    

        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution we found is this. Base on registry information:

[image]

You query the remote registry under HKLM\Software\Citrx\Ica\Session for all registry keys (which are the session id's). Then you read they value PublishedName from each sub key Connection. After that you match the session id from WTSQuerySessionInformation against the registry key name and you are done.

Some PowerShell PoC code would look like this:

```
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', 'YOURSERVER')
$RegKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Citrix\\ICA\\Session")
foreach ($sessionId in $RegKey.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    $sessionKey = $RegKey.OpenSubKey($sessionId + "\\Connection")
    if ($sessionKey -ne $null)
    {
        $sessionKey.GetValue("PublishedName")
        $sessionKey.Close()
    }
}    
$RegKey.Close()
$Reg.Close()
```