# RDP connection hook called twice for every connection

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want my application to hook remote connect and disconnect events for all sessions on the specified computer.

According to the documentation, I should call `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` function first:

```
WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd, NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS);
```

Then in the messages processor callback I should do the required stuff on `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` message type:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
    {
      // do stuff
      break;
    }
    }
}
```

It works very strange however. Every time I connect or disconnect to/from the computer where my application running, `WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT` or `WTS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT` called twice -- in one of these calls I can get user name and in another I can't (it's just an empty string).

```
  case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
  {
    const int reason = (int)wParam;
    const DWORD sessionId = (DWORD)lParam;
    switch (reason)
    {
    case WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT:
    {
        DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
        LPSTR pData = NULL;
        if (WTSQuerySessionInformationA(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, WTSUserName, &pData, &bytesReturned) == 0)
        {
          // Handle error
          break;
        }

        const std::string username = pData;
        WTSFreeMemory(pData);

        // do other stuff
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825385/wtsquerysessioninformation-returning-empty-strings) question but it has very strange accepted answer:

> Hmm, the answer appears to be that it's fairly normal for these fields
>   to be empty on a terminal services/RDP session

I don't understand why it actually works this way.

Comment: A wild guess here: Since you requested notifications for all sessions, maybe you also get a callback for *Session 0* (the non-interactive session)? Not getting a user name would be a strong indication for that.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, session ID for such connects and disconnects differs from 0 (it can be 2, 5 or whatever)

Comment: @IInspectable's point still stands. The system may make multiple connections for each user connection, some of which may be non-interactive. As a side note, Is there some reason you're using the ANSI version of `WTSQuerySessionInformation`?